# Is it possible to load an external file/class in a programmatic into the eclipse editor that is located outside the work space?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm attempting to load an external class into the Eclipse editor that is not located inside of the local workspace. **I should clarify that I am attempting to do this in an Eclipse plugin I am creating.**

How this needs to work for me:

1. I have a double-click event on a view that I have created.
2. On that double-click, I am getting a database field from SQL that returns an absolute path. (e.g. `C:\objects\sourceCode\class.java`)
3. Once the absolute path has been received from the database, I need to open the file inside of an instance of the Eclipse editor.

**NOTE:** I did attempt to read all the lines of the class I am attempting to open and create a temporary file inside of the Eclipse workspace directory and open that. However, I cannot seem to get this working.

---

**Therefore my question is:**

Does anyone know if this is even possible? If it is, can you point me to an article about doing something similar to this or provide the location of an example that may help me in my endeavours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that not all Eclipse editors support external files (the class file editor for example).

If the editor does support external files it does so by supporting `IURIEditorInput` as the editor input.

`FileStoreEditorInput` is the standard implementation of `IURIEditorInput`, use it like this:

```java
File file = .... the file to open

IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getStore(file.getURI());

IEditorInput editorInput = new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore);

IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.openEditor(editorInput, "id of editor to open");
```

As an alternative to the editor input and `page.openEditor` you can use the `IDE.openInternalEditorOnFileStore` method which will try and work out the id of the editor to open:

```java
IDE.openInternalEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
```

`IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE` in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in. `EFS` is `org.eclipse.core.filesystem.EFS` in the `org.eclipse.core.filesystem` plug-in.